# img SRC from first cell in a row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table such that each row is like this

```
<tr>
<td><input/> <img id="foo" src="redMinus.png"/></td>
some more tds
<td> <a onclick="wow('foo',$(this))"></a>
</tr>
```

I want to find out if the img in the first td has an src that contains "redMinus"
This is what I have but it doesnt seem to be working?

```
function wow(id, item){
var tr$ = item.parentNode.parentNode;
var details = tr$.find('img[src*="redMinus"]');
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing jQuery with DOM elements.

Change your code to

```
var details = item.closest("tr").find('img[src*="redMinus"]');
```

Comment: I was thinking that it would be something like this although it doesnt seem to be working :/  I put an alert right after it and it never gets to the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is given the name `item` within your function, but you are trying to use a variable with the name `item$` instead. Either rename the parameter or use the correct parameter name in the function.

Comment: sorry i mis-typed that when transfering it in

Answer (score 0):

```
var same = "redMinus" == $(this).parent('td').prev().children('img').attr('src').substring(0,7);
```

Comment: This won't find the image relative to the clicked anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wow(id, item){
var src = $('#' + id).attr('src');
var srcIndex = src.indexOf('redMinus');
if(srcIndex >= 0)
// redMinus is present in the string
else
// redMinus is not present in the string
}
```